# Run Launchd script back to back

Tags: launchd

I have a script I want to run with Launchd over and over. In other words, as soon as it finishes a run, I just want it to run again whether it errors out or finishes with a 0.

How do I do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use cron job. * * * * /path/to/script

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs